# Is PostgreSQL or ElasticSearch/Solr the right tool for this kind of queries?

Tags: postgresql, solr, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Here is an example of the current PostgreSQL query:

```sql
SELECT a.*, a.al_location <-> '(someLon, someLat)' AS d
FROM al_app.al_activity AS a
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', a.al_keywords) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'someKeyword')
ORDER BY d OFFSET 1000 LIMIT 50;
```

Basically it is against a table defined as follow:

```sql
CREATE TABLE al_app.al_activity_ (
    al_id serial,
    al_type int2 NOT NULL, 
    al_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL, 
    al_location point NOT NULL, 
    al_popularity int4 NOT NULL, 
    al_keywords char(1024) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT al_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (al_id) 
);
```

The query can filter by

- al_type
- al_keywords,

and sort by

- al_timestamp
- al_popularity
- distance (between user's location and al_location, as calculated in the above query example).

All queries are paged (50 activities per page).

We are using b-tree indexes on al_type, al_timestampe, and al_popularity. We are also using gist index on al_location and gin on to_tsvector('simple', al_keywords). The column al_keywords may hold multi-lingual text and some hashtags.

The al_activity table contains 6 million rows of sample random data, however we will be dealing with billions of rows in production environment. We noticed that query time gets longer and longer every time we increase the OFFSET number in the query to get next pages. Also, we do not know how should we scale as table and index get larger and larger in size (e.g. using partition tables and partial indexes).

The questions is: shall we work on optimizing this query in PostgreSQL, or simply switch to something like ElasticSearch/Solr to do the job? We do not have any problem switching expect that we are not sure if it will solve our problem?

Comment: Both Solr and Elasticsearch are capable of solving this problem with very little effort, and both would solve it in a more distributed fashion (personally, I strongly prefer Elasticsearch for this as it was designed up front for this purpose, and it allows JSON, which I find to be cleaner). The nice thing about PostgreSQL is the ability to have extra features exactly like what you are using that allow you to do it within the database until a time comes that it is not capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you are working on a single relation/table, I strongly believe that Solr or Elasticsearch is the best solution, since you get with no extra work several nice features such as [faceting search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) and many more. These features cannot be handled by SQL with the same efficiency and simplicity.

That said, if part of your requirements is to perform joins over multiple relations then you should perform these with your relational database and Solr is of no help.

Comment: How about our ordering requirements?

Comment: Solr provides sorting of indexed fields, see also sorting in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters